# Track mobile facebook ads to create cohort of users

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm developing an app on iOS integrated with the Facebook SDK.
Is it possible to check if a specific user just connect to my facebook app was acquired with a
[Facebook mobile ads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/mobile-ads/)?

This would be very usefull to create a cohort for each ads.
I know http://apsalar.com/ is doing this with their ApEngage product.

Comment: You can use one of these partner companies for additional analytics - https://developers.facebook.com/preferredmarketingdevelopers/mobile/measurement/. Does that help your question, or are you interested in measuring the number of users driven by the facebook campaign yourself ?

Comment: Hi @deesarus I'm most interested in measuring by myself.